# OWSTimer.exe recycles Application Pool when deploying solution

Tags: application-pool, owstimer

When I try to Unistall/Update the solution in Sharepoint using powershell the OWSTimer.EXE is resetting the Application pool of FrontEnd server. Even in Manifest file, I have mentioned `ResetWebServer="FALSE"`. How can I avoid the application pool recycled while installing?
In Sharepoint Logs I found:

```
Solution Deployment : Trying to stop Application pool Web_Frontend
.
.
Solution Deployment : Starting application pool Web_Frontend
```

Answer (score 0):

For Update solution, its internal functionality is that retracting the old version before deploying the new version. 
On Deploying/Retracting a solution, SharePoint will do iisreset.

Reference link: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543659.aspx

http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2011/03/10/sharepoint-solution-deploy-retract-upgrade-what-causes-an-your-sharepoint-farm-to-go-offline-iisreset-web-server-outage/